# Is it possible to read sensitive data from a stick that was removed from the PC?

Tags: security, usb-flash-drive

I have sensitive data on my personal pen drive, but the pen drive is read from a shared computer.

Could anyone read my sensitive data on the drive after it's been removed from the computer?
Are there any traces of it?

Comment: I don't get the question. If you stick your pen drive into a computer and there's sensitive stuff on it, nothing prevents people to copy stuff from the drive while it's plugged in.

Comment: So you are asking if a pen drive leaves a trace of data once it has been removed?

Answer (score 2):

If you open the content of your pen drive on the machine, then it will depend on the application as to whether there will be any trace of that data after closing the app and removing the drive.

If you had an application that was known not to copy the data elsewhere kept on the pen drive along with your data and only opened it from that, it would be more secure.

The best way might be to have a bootable linux installation on the pen drive, then the data could only be accessed by the booted OS. Of course this would only work on a machine that allows for the USB to boot.

If the data is that sensitive the storage device should also be encrypted, or the sensitive files should be encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Sensitive data can be harvested from a PC even if it is in standby mode, experts say. ... Researchers in Greece have discovered a security loophole that exploits the way computer memory works and could be used to harvest passwords and other sensitive data from a PC even if it is in standby mode.